# Flutter Web - Math and chemical symbols do not display correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I use flutter web 2.8.1 SDK and I faced these problem the Math and chemical symbols do not display correctly like these: "μ°℃℉㎍㎎㎏℥㏌㎚㎛㎜㎗㎖³²㎞㎝㎘㏄㏖㏒㎅㎆㎒㎑㎐㎉㎈㎇㎓㎾Ω㏑㏈㏐"

it appear like this:
"Î¼Â°ââãããâ¥ããããããÂ³Â²ãããããããããããããããã¾Î©ããã"

Comment: Pls show the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its just a text widget or textformfield widget  inside a scaffold